# How can I prevent multitouch in Xamarin Forms (specifically iOS project)?

Tags: ios, xamarin, multi-touch, xamarin.forms

We have a project with a chat page. In this page, when the user simultaneously taps the text entry box and outside of the box, we have undesired behavior. The text entry box moves to make room for the keyboard but the keyboard does not display. We have an Android and iOS project, but this only occurs in the iOS side.

I believe disabling multitouch would be a good option here because we do not use any multitouch gestures. However, I cannot find any information about how to successfully accomplish this. I have read about doing something like TouchesBegan, but it did not work for me.

Comment: It seems like you're modifying yourself the layout, if you surround your layout with an ScrollView the layout will automatically scroll to show the focused control when the keyboard is shown. If that's not an option and you want to modify the layout by yourself then instead of modify it on the focus event (or whatever event you used) you must register for the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification and UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, that will guarantee your code is only executed when the keyboard is shown/hidden. You can achieve that with a dependency service.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable multitouch throughout your app as the iOS SDK just does not allow this.

You could use [ExclusiveTouch](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/UIKit.UIView.ExclusiveTouch/) on a view to block touch events from other views while this one is receiving a touch event.